# Is there a characterization for graphs with independence number two?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

An *independent set* is a set of vertices in a graph, no two of which are adjacent.  A *maximum independent set* is an independent set of the largest possible size for a given graph. The size of a maximum independent set is called the *independence number* of $G$
and is usually denoted by $α(G)$.

It is easy to see that $α(G)=1$ if and only if $G$ is a complete graph. So if $α(G)=2$, is there also a characterization? And go on, for $α(G)=3$...

If there is no characterization, are there any necessary or sufficient conditions? For example, it appears that these graphs are not too sparse. Is there a lower bound on the number of their edges?

Comment: The complement of a graph with $\alpha(G)\leq 2$ is a *triangle-free* graph. There is no simple characterization. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle-free_graph for some information.

Comment: A graph has independence number $\le 2$ if and only if its complement is [triangle-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle-free_graph). Of course this is just a restatement of the definition, but this may still be a helpful keyword, and it may also indicate that a more nontrivial characterization doesn't exist.

Comment: One solution is (2,0)-colorable graphs. Their vertices can be partitioned in 2 cliques and they are complements of bipartite graphs.

Comment: @joro I don't understand what you mean.